# why can't send an object from parent component to child component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, components

parent component:

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-tripCreation',
    templateUrl: 
     ' <app-location (sendLocationDataEvent)="getLocationData($event)"></app-location>
      <app-tripInfo [locationDetails]="locationData"></app-tripInfo> '
    styleUrls: ['./tripCreation.component.scss']
 })

export class TripCreationComponent{
    locationData = {};

    getLocationData(response: any)
    {
        this.locationData = response
        console.log(this.locationData); // {pickAddressName: "KARWAN BAZAR, TEJGAON, DHAKA CITY", pickAreaID: 346, pickUnionID: 8195, pickThanaID: 512, …}

    }
}
```

first child component:

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-location',
    templateUrl: 
         '<button type="button" class="btn" id = "set" (click)="setData()" >setData</button>',
    styleUrls: ['./location.component.scss']
  })

  export class LocationComponent{
      locationDetails: any = {}; 
      @Output() sendLocationDataEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

      setData(){

          this.locationDetails.pickAddressName = "KARWAN BAZAR, TEJGAON, DHAKA CITY";
          this.locationDetails.pickAreaID = 346;
          this.locationDetails.pickUnionID = 8195;
          this.locationDetails.pickThanaID = 512;

          this.sendLocationDataEvent.emit(this.locationDetails);
      }
   }
```

second child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tripInfo',
    templateUrl: 
            '<div *ngIf="pickLocation">
                <p><span>pick location is: {{pickLocation}}</span></p> //pick location is:
            </div>',
    styleUrls: ['./tripInfo.component.scss']
})

export class TripInfoComponent{
    @Input() public locationDetails: any = {};
    pickLocation: srting = " ";

    constructor()
    {
        console.log(this.locationDetails); // {} -> a blank object
        this.pickLocation = this.locationData.pickAddressName;
    }
 }
```

From first child component I'm sending a data of object type to the parent component. Then again I'm passing that data from parent to second child component. The parent is getting the data object and logging it perfectly. But the second component is logging a blank object. I can't understand where am I miss-matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to react to the `OnChanges` event on the second child component like this:

```
export class TripInfoComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() public locationDetails: any = {};
    pickLocation: srting = " ";

    constructor() { }

    ngOnChanges (changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log(changes.locationDetails);
        this.pickLocation = changes.locationDetails.currentValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method. But it can't detect the change and don't even logging anything, not even a blank object.

Comment: yes, it worked perfectly. I did a silly mistake. but now it's okay. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setter to set pick location in `TripInfoComponent` class (the code in the constructor is executed just on the component class instantiation):

```js
export class TripInfoComponent {
    @Input() 
    set locationDetails(locationData: any) {
      this.pickLocation = locationData ? locationData.pickAddressName : '';
      this._locationDetails = locationData;
    }
    get locationDetails(): any {return this._locationDetails;}
    private _locationDetails: any = {};

    pickLocation: string = " ";
 }
```

The getter is not mandatory. Add it only if you need public access to location details. Otherwise, you can use the private member `_locationDetails`.